# Get count of invoices for last three months?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, ssas-2012

Thank you all. This is my MDX query and this returns the count of invoices generated on March 2015 and works like a charm!

```
 WITH 
  SET [mySet] AS 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] * {[Measures].[Sales #]} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[setDistCount] AS 
    DistinctCount([mySet]) 
SELECT 
  {
  [Measures].[Sales #]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]} ON 0
  FROM [F1_SalesBI]
);
```

Output is like:

```
            Sales #
Store 1     156
Store 2      56
Store 3     546
...
Store 10     69
```

But I wish to get report like this:

```
            March     February     January
Store 1     156       656          145
Store 2      56        89           41
Store 3     546       215          215
...
Store 10     69        69           96
```

For my desired output, how am I supposed query? Please help me!

Comment: it's working like a charm now? But this measure `[Measures].[setDistCount]` is not included anywhere apart from the `WITH` clause?

Comment: Yup that shouldn't be there. That's not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Generate` looks like it is over-complicating the situation maybe something a little simpler is all that is required:

```
SELECT 
  {
   [Calendar].[Month].[March 2015],
   [Calendar].[Month].[February 2015],
   [Calendar].[Month].[January 2015],
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] ON 1
FROM [F1_SalesBI]
WHERE [Measures].[Sales #];
```

To make this dynamic so it only ever shows the last three months in your cube then use the `Tail` function like this:

```
SELECT 
  Tail([Calendar].[Month].[Month].members,3) ON 0 //<< I've assumed this is ok but you may need to use [Calendar].[Month].members
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] ON 1
FROM [F1_SalesBI]
WHERE [Measures].[Sales #];
```

Comment: Will work, **but** 1. You don't really need a sub select if you are explicitly mentioning the members. 2. For a typical scenario, where one might wish to replace march with some other month, there is lot of work involved. 3. Thus not suited for reporting scenarios.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti - agree about sub-select

Comment: having march in sub select reduces the scope to March. So effectively there is only one month.Your solution wont work I guess

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti how do you know this? It could be `[Calendar].[Month].[Cal Mnth].members`

Comment: Correct. What I meant was that syntactically that's fine.

Comment: BTW, nice to catch up after a hiatus. Its a shame SO doesn't have a chat window.

Comment: Thanks a trillion @whytheq. Works brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Have the set created this way

```
WITH SET Last3Months AS
GENERATE
(
    [Calendar].[Month].[March 2015],    
    {[Calendar].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(2):[Calendar].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER}
)
```

This will create a set of last 3 months including the current month(provided in set's definition)

Then the below query will get you what you need.

```
SELECT 
  Last3Months ON 0

 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group].MEMBERS ON 1

 FROM [F1_SalesBI]

WHERE {[Measures].[Sales #]}
```

Comment: Error, "The Month hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis."

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti why bother with `generate`?

Comment: To have months in slicer and one axis is not possible. Having month in Sub-selects leads to the `[All]` member in the set, so again not suitable! So finally went with `GENERATE`

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti you may aswell just use `[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015].LAG(2):[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]`

Comment: Correcto! Can be used.

Comment: Thanks a trillion @Sourav. Works brilliant!